# How to improve my SELECT performance

Tags: performance

I have a table called fct containing 250 million records , indexed(dwh_key,end_date) and partitioned by end_date(daily)

I have this select:

```
SELECT FCT.ACCOUNT_NUMBER, 
       FCT.PRODUCT_CODE, 
       FCT.PRODUCT_START_DATE, 
       FCT.PRODUCT_END_DATE, 
       FCT.SVC_FEATURE_ATTRIBUTE, 
       FCT.SVC_FEATURE_ATTR_START_DATE, 
       FCT.END_DATE 
FROM
 FCT 
WHERE
 FCT.PRODUCT_CODE IN ($$prm1,
                      $$prm2, 
                      $$prm3)
OR
(
FCT.END_DATE = TO_DATE('31/12/2999', 'DD/MM/YYYY')
AND
FCT.SVC_FEATURE_ATTRIBUTE in($$prm4,
                             $$prm5)
)
```

It takes approximately 20min+ .

I need to make it faster.. but can't think of something to do here..

Comment: First, split it in 2 unions select

Comment: Whether your current index is used? Did you check the execution plan

Comment: You mention only one index: `(dwh_key, end_date)` but do not set a filter condition for `dwh_key` in your query.  So, it's probably NOT using that index, unless `dwh_key` has _very_ low cardinality (in which case it might do an `INDEX SKIP SCAN`).  Are there other indexes?  If so, are they locally partitioned or globally partitioned indexes?

Comment: That's the table DDL, I can't change it because it can harm other processes performances .. @MatthewMcPeak

Comment: You can make an `INVISIBLE` index.  The optimizer will not use such an index unless there is an explicit hint for it.  In that way, you can create in index and be confident that it is not affecting any other queries.

Answer (score 2):

Databases often have a hard time optimizing conditions with `OR`.  So, try `UNION` or `UNION ALL`:

```
SELECT . . .
FROM FCT 
WHERE FCT.PRODUCT_CODE IN ($$prm1, $$prm2, $$prm3)
UNION
SELECT . . .
FROM FCT 
WHERE FCT.END_DATE = TO_DATE('31/12/2999', 'DD/MM/YYYY') AND
      FCT.SVC_FEATURE_ATTRIBUTE in ($$prm4, $$prm5);
```

Then, you can optimize these subqueries with two indexes:  `FC(PRODUCT_CODE)` AND `FCT(END_DATE, SVC_FEATURE_ATTRIBUTE)`.  If the query returns lots of rows, I would suggest using `UNION ALL` like this:

```
SELECT . . .
FROM FCT 
WHERE FCT.PRODUCT_CODE IN ($$prm1, $$prm2, $$prm3)
UNION ALL
SELECT . . .
FROM FCT 
WHERE FCT.END_DATE = TO_DATE('31/12/2999', 'DD/MM/YYYY') AND
      FCT.SVC_FEATURE_ATTRIBUTE in ($$prm4, $$prm5) AND
      FCT.PRODUCT_CODE NOT IN ($$prm1, $$prm2, $$prm3)
```

And the second index should be: `FCT(END_DATE, SVC_FEATURE_ATTRIBUTE, PRODUCT_CODE)`.

Comment: add a end_date condition in the first query, supposed not null

Comment: @LonGdueZBOO . . .I do not see that condition in the OP's question.

Comment: Sure but it sould be usefull to make use of partition.

Comment: First, thx for the reply . Adding indexes is not possible in my case, since this table is being used in a lot of different places and it can harm their performances. The query returns about 40k records and union all is not good since it can result in duplicates.. Do you think in and not in should perform better then union?

Comment: The second approach might be ok, but it you don't have indexes on the relevant columns, then it probably won't improve performance.